# ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: pages

Tags: python, exception, pylons, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN as my open data portal. It's written in Python using Pylons framework. I just want to add a new page similar to about page to display the terms and conditions to the users. About page comes built in.

So I installed [ckanext-pages](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages) using pip command. What I did was below

```
1. # Activate your CKAN virtual environment
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate

2. # Install the pages extension.
pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages.git#egg=ckanext-pages'
```

But now I end up with below error which is given when a requested plugin cannot be found.

> ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: pages

Plugin resides on below path

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src
```

Please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your virtualenv activated, run `python setup.py develop` in the ckanext-pages folder. This will register the plugin so CKAN can find it.

Comment: I already did that. But it does not work. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: The exeption means that the plugin isn't installed in your virtualenv. I do wonder whether you've run `python setup.py develop` as amercader says: `. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate`, `cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-pages`, `python setup.py develop`

Comment: Please see the updated question. Please let me know how to fix this. I'm really stuck.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after running `python setup.py develop`?

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue. Double-check which `paster` you are using by command:

```
which paster
```

it must show you `paster` from your current `virtualenv`, which was `/usr/lib/ckan/default` in your case

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying @amercader answer, and getting error13 permission denied, with your venv activated:

- `which python`,  this will get the path to python in your venv, grap that
- run  `sudo the_path_you_just_grapped setup.py develop`

then run the database initialization as in [here](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages#database-initialization)