# PluginNotFoundException: my_theme

Tags: python, themes, ckan

We use our own Plugin my_theme

And get an Error:

```
PluginNotFoundException: my_theme
```

There was a [similiar problem with solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038591/ckan-plugins-core-pluginnotfoundexception-pages) but this those not work (4 years ago)

CKAN: 2.7.2

OS: Centos 7.4

```
ckan.plugins =webpage_view stats text_view recline_view pdf_view 
geojson_view my_theme resource_proxy
ckan.views.default_views = webpage_view geojson_view pdf_view text_view  recline_view
```

I installed the Theme with(as described in the manual):

```
 . /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
python setup.py develop
```

How to proceed?

Comment: You need to be in the extension directory when you do 'python setup.py develop'. Do you want to try that bit again?

Comment: @DRead
i was in the same directory,
solved it though the Theme still had SELinux home_root_t Context so CKAN/Python could not found it

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. Please do develop that into an Answer, to help the next person with this issue.